# Remove empty row from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to check and remove any empty row in my table mapped to an array in javascript.

Sample array would be like below.

```
1   2   3
4   5   6

7   8   9
```

Now this array is having 4 rows and 3rd one is empty which I want to remove. How to do that. I tried using  if(adata[i]) is not null, but that wont work since an indivdual value can be null. i want to check for complete row being null

Comment: Are your all lines separated by a "\n character"?

Comment: show the actual array content

Comment: Are you asking how to delete an element in an array? [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This short code should match your requirement :

```
var input = [[1,,3], [11,, ,12], [,,,,,], [37,38,39]];
var result = input.filter(element => element.join("") != "");
console.log(result); // [ [ 1, , 3 ], [ 11, , , 12 ], [ 37, 38, 39 ] ]
```

Edit : for ES5 you'll write rather

```
var result = input.filter(function(element) {return element.join("") != ""});
```

Comment: Yes all lines are seperated by a '\n' since it is copied from a excel.I was able to parse and add values into array. Now want to remove empty record. The record '7 8 9' should come at index 2 now.

Comment: @Kevin: I get an error if I use var result = input.filter(element => element.join("") != ""); Error is:element not defined

Comment: Strange Justin, would we have different interpretor ?  That works perfectly on my plateform. What plateform do you test on ?

Comment: I am using eclipse Mars on windows7.

Comment: I also use Eclipse Mars with the plugin ENIDE for Node.js and that works fine. but you can write this instead var result = input.filter(function(element) {return element.join("") != ""});